# Why I receive `6C0B` instead of data that I expected?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I now have a Hello World project according this [link](https://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/) and I made its .cap

file successfully. I have "DE-ABCM_TB" reader and a SAM card also.

My applet AID is `01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00`

I could select my applet on the card.( I sent SELECT APDU command via "DualCard

Ver 2.8"/ pcsc tab) . I now must be receive hello in hex format when I send

`8000000000`. But i receive 6C0B ! Why did I get this response and

how can I resolve this ? I searched but no solving found.

Comment: For your information  : 1-Use google.com for this kind of problems. 2-use "**I**" instead of "**i**", In English, they use this word in uppercase form always. moreover start sentences with uppercase letters.(I correct them in this question) -  
And congrats dear bro, you finished the hard steps by now :) good lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't searched good enough!

If you do a quick look at status words table you will see `SW1=6CXX` means **Wrong Le  field; SW2 encodes the exact number of available data bytes**

So you must send the below command:

`80|00|00|00|0B`!

Table of Status Words :

[image]

Comment: @soheylaabbbb No I'm not! I'm a little student here also. I added the table of Status Words to the question. Keep it. you'll need it.

Comment: i am so weak in APDUs commanding. How can i learn creating APDUs for other instructions? I want learn it fully.please direct me or give me a good pdf or link if possible.

Comment: @soheylaabbbb 1-www.google.com 2- Use **I** instead of **i**!

Comment: I googled very much but subjects were outspread. I want a comprehensive teaching. Can u direct me better? Or if possible give some keywords for my search. I am weak at this kind of searches...

Comment: please see this my other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925504/how-can-i-credit-or-debit-more-than-1-byte-to-from-card

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/learnmore/javacard-books-1971218.html

Comment: @soheylaabbbb Please don't use comments to refer people to your other questions.